# Lodash filter a collection with nested values and a sub string comparison

Tags: javascript, filter, ecmascript-6, filtering, lodash

I would like to filter a list of Users based on his department ID (if selected), organization ID (if selected), role (if selected, need to match with any of the roles of a user - a user can have multiple roles) and ***compare with a substring - name***.

Below is the working code I've written. But this has 2 loops/filters.

```
const {orgId, deptId, role, searchInputValue} = this.state
const filter = {}
if (orgId) {
  filter.organization = {
    id: orgId
  }
}
if (deptId) {
  filter.department = {
    id: deptId
  }
}
if (role) {
  filter.roles = [role]
}
let filteredUsers = lodash.filter(this.props.initialUsers, filter)
if (searchInputValue) {
  filteredUsers = filteredUsers.filter(item =>
    lodash.startsWith(item.name.toLowerCase(), searchInputValue))
}
```

How can I merge both these loops or filters into a single one?
How can I specify the `searchInputvalue` in the same `filter` object and avoid the second users list filtering?

**NB:** I would like to know the solution to simplify the above code **using lodash with a filter object passed** and is not looking for a solution where,
 - I can just use the basic array.filter and have a function to check all my conditions
 - Or use the lodash filter and pass in a function to check all my conditions.

Comment: So, you are asking how to use the lodash `filter` predicate to do something it doesn't normally do - perform a comparison against a substring of a property rather than the whole property value?

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to write yourself a custom function anyway (see [lodash.iteratee](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#iteratee)) in order to accomplish your `startsWith` comparison. But, the upside is that once you write the custom iteratee, it will be used every time you call `lodash.filter(...)`.